# Apache metacharacters

Tags: regex, linux, apache, httpd.conf

I need to set up 500 different virtualhost in apache (httpd), with the same configuration. I thought it could be possible to use metacharacters or loops, instead of copying the same 500 times...
I tried to search some information, but I couldn't find any workaround. Does anybody know something regarding this issue?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [mod_macro](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html) might be what you are looking for.
Straight from the documentation:

> Provides macros within Apache httpd runtime configuration files, to
>   ease the process of creating numerous similar configuration blocks.
>   When the server starts up, the macros are expanded using the provided
>   parameters, and the result is processed as along with the rest of the
>   configuration file.